# How to get 'TZ' with out '$TZ' being set?

Tags: linux, bash, ruby

I writing a Ruby program. I need a way to get something like `America/New_York` as `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` and `require "tzinfo"` can't get my current timezone. (Note that `Time.now.zone` can get things like `EST` but I need the tz database format, e.g. `America/New_York`.) Though the eazy way to do this is to just have the user set `$TZ`, `TZ='America/New_York'; export TZ` or `tzselect`. I'm looking for a way to do this without having the user set `TZ`. Is there some system file I can load, or a network location I can query?

I need the timezone for things like.

```
require "active_support/core_ext/time/zones"

Time.zone = ENV['TZ']
p Time.zone.now # Returns current time in the local time zone using ActiveSupport.
```

Comment: Why do you think you need `America/New_York`? Also, what distribution are you on?

Comment: I'm on Xubuntu 12.04 and I need the user's local time zone, not necessarily `America/New_York`.

Comment: Why? How is it going to be useful to you? That's just the name of a file that may contain anything. Wouldn't strftime("%z") be more useful?

Comment: I wish it was, but active support requires the Olsen/"tz database" format the `$TZ` environment variable is required for my app now but I may switch to geolocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On glibc, the default timezone is kept in `/etc/localtime`. This may be a symlink to a file in the tz database (in which case you could simply readlink), but there is no guarantee - it may be a hardlink or even a copy. In that case, you would have to read the file and then compare it to all the files in the tz data directory.

I am not sure what purpose you think getting the value `America/New_York` will serve.

Comment: This is what I was looking for: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/12523283/1058897> this could be translated to ruby but I'll just require that `$TZ` is set.